# PHP mysql_query inside FOR only works first loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I´m trying to update some different registers in a mysql database sending the commands from a FOR loop in php, but the query is only done the 1st loop. Here´s the code:

```
$conexion = mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $pass) or die ("Error establishing connection with the Database");
mysql_select_db($db,$conexion) or die("Error selecting the Database");
$j=0;
for ($i=0;$i<count($notifs);$i++){
$sql="UPDATE tef SET notif='$notifs[$i]' WHERE sn_rec='$unsersn_recs[$j]';";
echo $sql."<br>";
$res=mysql_query($sql, $conexion) or die (mysql_error());           
$j++;
}
mysql_close($conexion);
```

The query text is correctly done (the echo shows the different lines created), but the changes in the database are done only in the 1st loop (1st query) and I don´t receive any error. What may I be missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be using prepared statements

Comment: how is $notifs defined?

Comment: `if($res=mysql_query($sql, $conexion){/*do something here*/}else{die(mysql_error());`
Also better use mysqli_* or PDO because mysql_* functions are marked as deprecated

Comment: @demonking This is equivalent to `$res = mysql_query(...) or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: check value of $notifs. may be its getting value 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wonderful example where you should use prepared statements.

I give you an example which is also secure against SQL injections.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Error establishing connection!");
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tef SET notif=? WHERE sn_rec=?");

$j=0;
for ($i=0;$i<count($notifs);$i++) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $notifs[$i], $unsersn_recs[$j]);
    $stmt->execute();
    if(!empty($stmt->error)) echo $stmt->error;
    $j++;
}
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

Hint: If `notif` or `sn_rec` are varchar/text types, just replace the 'i' with a 's' in `bind_param()`.

Comment: Great Marcel, I´ve used your code and worked like a charm! I´d love to know why my code didn´t work to understand it, can you guess why? Thanks a lot to everyone helping!

Comment: You're welcome. When this solves your problem, please accept the answer with the green mark on the left ;) - Maybe the connection is blocked by mysql_query() after the first execution..but I don't think so. mysql_* are deprecated, so it's not very easy to get information about the problem. - In future just use mysqli and use prepared statements. They are also secure against SQL-Injections, which your old code isn't ;)